# Weighted average function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to create a function that takes the weighted average of an array. I am creating a presentation that shows rates ($) and revenue by market for a client with a weighted average rate per product at the bottom. I could manually find each markets % share of total revenue and then multiply each market's % factor by it's rate and then add all of these values up to find the weighted average rate, but I want to create a function to do it for me. I want to do the following:

For the following client data (fake):

```
-Asia       $16      $200,000
-Europe     $9       $50,000
-N. America $21      $100,000
-Africa     $25      $250,000
```

I need to find the weighted average rate across all markets.

```
Function WeightedAverage(array, weightarray)     
#"array" being {$16,$9,$21,$25} and "weightarray" being {$200,000, $50,000, $100,000, $250,000}

WeightedAverage = SumProduct(array, weightvalues) 

weightvalues = an array of values like so {$200,000/sum(weightarray), $50,000/sum(weightarray), $100,000/sum(weightarray), $250,000/sum(weightarray)}

End Function
```

This should return a weighted average rate of `$20`.

Can someone help me accomplish this?

Comment: sumproduct(array,weightarray)/sum(weightarray)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need VBA -- a simple formula works. If your data is in cells A1:C4, enter the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B4,C1:C4/SUM(C1:C4))
```

In this version of the formula I am treating `C1:C4/SUM(C1:C4)` much like an array formula, which converts the array of numbers (200,000, 50,000, etc.) into the corresponding array of weights (0.33, 0.083, etc.). In many contexts, this would require explicitly treating the expression as an array formula, but `sumproduct` is a rather powerful function which can apply whole-array formulas to its arguments. See [this](http://exceluser.com/formulas/sumproduct_12.htm) for a nice discussion.

In this particular case

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B4,C1:C4)/SUM(C1:C4)
```

also works and corresponds to Merely Useful's answer in the comments, but I'll leave my answer as it is since it is useful to know that `sumproduct` can in effect evaluate array formulas in its arguments, even if the overall sumproduct isn't entered as an array formula itself.

Comment: I think there is no need to CSE this formula.

Comment: @BrakNicku -- you are correct. I was thinking in terms of array formulas and used CSE (and saw the expected result) so didn't notice that it wasn't needed. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't your second rightmost parenthesis in a wrong place? Shouldn't it be before the division?

Comment: @martin -- it works both ways. Based on OP's problem description I first thought of it as a problem of constructing an array of weights before feeding it to `sumproduct`, but sumproduct is able to accept as arguments arrays which outside of sumproduct would need to be entered as array formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need a VBA function for this, an array formula will do:

```
=SUM(A1:A4*B1:B4)/SUM(B1:B4)
```

(Press Ctrl+Enter when entering the formula)